# Slow MySQL query when the IN list is long

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.6, query-performance

I have 3 tables, namely: product, product_has_category, category:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `des` text COMMENT 'description',
  `price` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Price of product',
  `vendor` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Where this product is from , can be derived from p_url field',
  `p_url` text,
  `hide_flag` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'When you dont want to show a product but dont want to delete it either. 0 = not hidden, 1 = hidden',
  `del_flag` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Delete Flag 1 = deleted , 0 = not deleted'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=58897 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
ALTER TABLE `product`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD KEY `del_flag` (`del_flag`,`hide_flag`), ADD KEY `name` (`del_flag`,`name`);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_has_category` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=78705 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
ALTER TABLE `product_has_category`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD KEY `fk_product_has_category_category1_idx` (`category_id`), ADD KEY `fk_product_has_category_product1_idx` (`product_id`);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `des` text COMMENT 'Description field',
  `lft` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rgt` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'parent_id , allows for hybrid nested set model to speed up search where depth = 1 only'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1383 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD KEY `category_lft_idx` (`lft`);
```

I have a query to look up products when they match the category that the user is searching for.

Each product can be linked to multiple categories, also the number of categories that will be defined in the query is based on what the user chooses.

As such my query has become slow due to number of category ids that are being checked.

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    `product`.`id`, `product`.`name`, `product`.`des`, `product`.`del_flag`,
    `product`.`vendor`, `product`.`price`, `product`.`p_url`
FROM `product`
INNER JOIN `product_has_category` as `product_category`
    ON `product_category`.`product_id` = `product`.`id`
WHERE `product`.`del_flag` = '0'
AND `product_category`.`category_id` IN
(
    '189', '190', '191', '192', '193', '194', '195', '196', '197', '198',
    '199', '200', '331', '332', '333', '334', '335', '336', '337', '338',
    '339', '340', '207', '208', '209', '210', '211', '212', '213', '214',
    '215', '216', '217', '218', '219', '220', '221', '222', '223', '224',
    '225', '226', '227', '228', '229', '230', '231', '232', '233', '234',
    '235', '236', '237', '238', '239', '240', '241', '242', '243', '244',
    '245', '246', '247', '248', '249', '250', '251', '252', '253', '254',
    '255', '256', '257', '258', '259', '260', '261', '262', '263', '264',
    '265', '282', '283', '284', '285', '286', '287', '288', '267', '268',
    '269', '270', '271', '272', '273', '274', '275', '276', '277', '278',
    '279', '280', '281', '289', '290', '291', '292', '293', '294', '295',
    '308', '309', '310', '311', '312', '313', '314', '315', '316', '298',
    '299', '300', '301', '302', '303', '304', '305', '306', '307', '323',
    '324', '325', '326', '327', '328', '329', '318', '319', '320', '321',
    '322', '341', '342', '343', '344', '345', '346', '347', '348', '349',
    '350', '351', '352', '353', '354', '355', '356', '357', '358', '374',
    '375', '376', '377', '378', '379', '380', '381', '382', '360', '361',
    '362', '383', '384', '385', '386', '387', '388', '364', '389', '390',
    '391', '392', '366', '393', '394', '395', '368', '369', '370', '396',
    '397', '398', '399', '400', '401', '402', '403', '404', '372', '405',
    '406', '409', '410', '411', '412', '413', '414', '415', '416', '417',
    '418', '419', '420', '421', '422', '423', '424', '425', '426', '427',
    '428', '429', '430', '431', '432', '433', '434', '435', '436', '437',
    '438', '439', '440', '441', '442', '443', '452', '453', '454', '455',
    '456', '457', '458', '459', '460', '461', '462', '463', '464', '465',
    '466', '447', '448', '449', '450', '451', '467', '468', '469', '470',
    '471', '472', '475', '476', '477', '478', '479', '480', '481', '482',
    '483', '484', '485', '486', '487'
)
ORDER BY `name` asc
```

MySQL explain shows me the following:

[image: mysqlexplain]

This problem did not exists when the query was small.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT `product`.`id`, `product`.`name`, `product`.`des`, `product`.`del_flag`, `product`.`vendor`, `product`.`price`, `product`.`p_url`
FROM `product`
INNER JOIN `product_has_category` as `product_category` ON `product_category`.`product_id` = `product`.`id`
WHERE `product`.`del_flag` = '0'
AND `product_category`.`category_id` IN('189',  '487')
ORDER BY `name` asc
```

When the number of categories to search was small mysql explain showed the following:

[image: mysqlexplain2]

I'm not a DBA so i would appreciate any help to help me optimize this code to better function.

Comment: How many products do you have and how many of them will this list of categories select? Why are you using `use index (PRIMARY)` ? With that you forbid mysql to adapt when things change.

Comment: I've edited to put in the create statements and the mysql explain results. 

I have about 100,000 products , this list will limit the output to 12 product per page

Comment: And how many of those 100K products belong to the selected categories?

Comment: I've remove use index (Primary), that was a step that i found from this site http://erniemiller.org/2011/08/30/slow-mysql-query-ill-give-you-a-hint/

Comment: each category can have unlimited products , so when a user selects a parent category , the sql query will be huge as it will have to search each child category whether they have products and return 12. 

As the user browses in depth in to the next category the query will gradually become smaller as the category ids being check will narrow down

Comment: I see - but that will become the version with few categories - but how many of them does the "big" one return? Other thing: use/force/ignore index can be quite powerful but you have to know what it does and why it helps. I tried 2 modifications of your query in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0bfbf/4 and the third one looks best but as it does not have your data it may work differently for you.

Comment: Have you tried writing the selections to a temporary table then `JOIN`ing to that, rather than using `IN`?

Answer (score 1):

It is *more* efficient to do a table scan rather than use an index in the case where you need to touch more than 20% of the rows.  The optimizer knows this and uses it to good advantage.  (The "20%" varies with the phase of the moon.)

Don't use a 4-byte `INT` for a flag; use a `TINYINT UNSIGNED`.

In `product_has_category`, don't have an `id`, instead use

```
PRIMARY KEY(product_id, category_id),
INDEX(      category_id, product_id)
```

That will make using the table more efficient.

(When showing `CREATE TABLE`, include the indexes inside, not as an afterthought.  Or simply do `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for displaying here.)